# MAPI Schema or URN Schema equivalent to finding mailitem.ConversationID()

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I have VBA code that uses advancesearch and getTable().

In getTable the default properties do not include conversationID but I can add columns that include schema properties.

I cannot find a conversationID schema in MAPI or URN or anything schema for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, `ConversationID` is not based on any single MAPI property. 
`ConversationIndex`, on the other hand, is based on `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` MAPI property. Is using that property an option?

Comment: Is PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX as reliable as ConversationID? I could not find much info to compare the too.

Comment: Yes, PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX is the native MAPI property used by Outlook when threading the conversations. Take a look at messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).

Comment: It is a binary property - you get back an array.

Comment: I never would have guessed that. I found a function to convert it but I am not sure how i would use it unless i attach it to the mail item. Can i use it in nextrow() somehow such as this: BinaryToString(nextRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102"))

Comment: You can convert it to hex either explicitly in your code or using PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString